# Mount point not found exception in Springboot application

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

My application is running on Linux.

I have the following line in the code. Note that dirPath exists and it is mounted.

```
Files.getFileStore(dirPath).getUsableSpace()
```

I am randomly getting the following exception, after which I have to restart the application. Can you please help me to resolve this.

```
java.io.IOException: Mount point not found
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileStore.findMountEntry(java.base/LinuxFileStore.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileStore.<init>(java.base/UnixFileStore.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileStore.<init>(java.base/LinuxFileStore.java:44) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(java.base/LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(java.base/LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:39) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(java.base/UnixFileSystemProvider.java:368)~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.nio.file.Files.getFileStore(java.base/Files.java:1461)~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

Comment: Give us some more details, what is the mount point? Is it docker container or sth else? Check out also this bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165852

Comment: It is not docker container. dirPath is a directory in my machine. I looked in to above openjdk jira, but didn't got the resolution.